# Finiding orientation of a rod

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, rotations

I have rod made with small spheres like this[image]. All the spheres together make this rigid rod.I have coordinate of all small spheres in 3d thus I can be able to find out it's center of mass and most extreme point of both sides. The rod can rotate in $\theta$ and $\phi$ direction as per spherical coordinate system. [image]

So my question is how can I calculate both rotations from its initial position coordinates? What is the formula to calculate that if I have given only coordinates?

Comment: This is not understandable.  Try to clarify your question, please.  In particular, why can't you just apply the rotation to the center of each sphere?

Comment: @saulspatz Why do I need to apply rotation to center of each sphere? I am thinking only center of mas coordinate and extreme points(spheres) should fine to measure its rotation. as all the sphere together make this rod as a rigid body..(many atoms together build a nanorod)

Comment: As I said, I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Why not just apply the rotation to the center of mass of the whole system, if it's a rigid body?  Clarify your question.

Comment: What is the point of the spheres to the problem? Why don't you just consider it a cylinder with a defined length and radius?

Comment: @RonJensen-WeareallMonica actually the sphere does not effect anything..it is just to explain how the rod is made and how i will able to get coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we can simplify the shape to a cylinder and know the location of the center of each end cap, which are Cartesian coordinate points $p_1$ and $p_2$. We then choose one of the points as the origin and subtract it from the other, e.g. $p_0 = p_2 - p_1$. We then calculate $$ \theta = \arctan(p_{0_y} / p_{0_x}) $$ correcting for quadrant, of course.

To get $\phi$ we need to find $r = |{p_0}|$ or $ r=\sqrt{p_{0_x}^2+p_{0_y}^2+p_{0_z}^2}$ and then $$ \phi = \arccos(p_{0_z} / r ) $$

Note that if we had defined $p_0 = p_1 - p_2$ then $\theta$ and $\phi$ would both be 180° off.